# NSDateFormatter in iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring, twitter, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm using the Twitter API to download the number of tweets because I need them in my app for iOS. I'm using [this function](https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=user_name) to do this. The problem is that I need to know the day, month and year when the tweet was written.

The date that comes back is like this:

```
Thu Oct 25 10:34:58 +0000 2012
```

But I need a date like this format:

```
25/10/2012 10:34
```

So, I want to transform the first format to the second format. I've tried to do it with NSDate and NSDateFormatter, obtaining a NSDate with the first NSString, and after transforming this NSDate in the second NSString, but I didn't get it.

```
    NSArray *dateArray = [tweets valueForKey:@"created_at"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateArray objectAtIndex:0];   // Thu Oct 25 10:34:58 +0000 2012

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSLog(@"%@", date);

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSString *realDateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@", realDateStr);
```

The two NSLogs each return null.

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: hm, I think the idea here is right.  I'm not sure if NSDateFormatter likes having it's format changed back and forth like that, I might try doing this with 2 seperate NSDateFormatters: one to go from twitter date string -> NSDate object, then a second to go from that NSDate object -> NSString like "dd/MM/yyyy".  Also, maybe put in a `NSLog(@"%@",dateString);` right after your `NSString *dateString = [dateArray objectAtIndex:0];` to make sure you're getting the string from twitter the way you think you are.

Comment: dateString is Thu Oct 25 10:34:58 +0000 2012, so has the format expected. The problem is that the line NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString] return null value. I think that the date style NSDateFormatterMediumStyle isn't the correct to format this NSString, but I don't know how to format it whith setDateFormat:.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure offhand on that either, I'd have to play with it a little. Abellina's post looks about right tho, try that.

Comment: Remember the Xcode debugger display date/time UTC+0

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the date format originally to parse out the date string you are getting, like this:

```
NSString *dateString = @"Thu Oct 25 10:34:58 +0000 2012";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@", date);

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"];

NSString *realDateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", realDateStr);
```

Comment: The result is the same, date and realDateStr are null :\

Comment: I tested this code, and I didn't get nulls. You may have something wrong in your array then in that case. Try it with the code exactly as I shared it above. I get:

`2012-10-25 10:34:58 +0000` for the first, and 
`25/10/2012 05:34` for the second NSLog.

Comment: I have tried it with your code exactly and I obtained null in the two outputs :\

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method:

```
NSString* string=@"26-01-2014";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-mm-yyyy"];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
NSLog(@"Date = %@",date);
```